# Mongoose duplicate key error with addToSet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mern

This is my Schema, the application is an Instagram clone.
The Likes schema is there which has reference of the unique id of the User

For this, I'm using addToSet but a Duplicate key error comes up.
Below is the schema model and query implementation.

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  caption: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  postUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  likes: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "User"}],
  comments: [
    {
      text: String,
      postedBy: { type: ObjectId, ref: "User" },
      time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    },
  ],
  postedBy: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

I'm getting this error

```
{
    "operationTime": "6960585855740149761",
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "codeName": "DuplicateKey",
    "keyPattern": {
        "likes": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
        "likes": "6093b5b628bce2002328eed8"
    },
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": "6960585855740149761",
        "signature": {
            "hash": "+/RdCIov1VsbZ8tXqprjn4ca940=",
            "keyId": "6918360005028610050"
        }
    },
    "name": "MongoError"
}
```

The element I'm sending from frontend is not present in the Likes array
Still, this error comes up

This is query implementation

```
router.put("/like", requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const postData = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.body.postId,
      {
        $addToSet: { likes: [req.user._id] }, //pushing in to array
                // { $addToSet: { locations: ["New York", "Texas", "Detroit"] } }
      }
    ).populate("postedBy", "_id name dpUrl");
    return res.json(postData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.json({ error });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, `$addToSet` is used to add a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array and the operation will fail.

It seems that you might be adding same userIds to the array and because of which you might be getting the error.

Try changing:

```
{
        $addToSet: { likes: req.user._id }, //pushing unique ID of the user
                // { $addToSet: { locations: ["New York", "Texas", "Detroit"] } }
      }
```

For more details, check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).

Comment: No, I'm not adding the same value to the array.
The solution you gave I have tried already. Didn't work. I checked out official docs but didn't help.

Comment: But then I have to do one more query to check if data is present or not in the array. The push method was working though.

Comment: So, I would suggest you to check the data you are passing.

Comment: I did, correct data (that is req.user._id)  is being passed to Likes array.